# MySQL get records of last date of each month

Tags: php, mysql, subquery, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I need to fetch records of `last date` of each month based on the dates of records in the database table. Now, if I fetch the last dates of each month in my table using following query:

```
SELECT MAX(`date`) AS max_date 
FROM cpr
WHERE YEAR(`date`) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
GROUP BY YEAR(`date`), MONTH(`date`);
```

It returns the last dates of each month perfectly as below:

```
max_date
2023-01-31
2023-02-27
2023-03-31
2023-04-27
2023-05-31
2023-06-06
```

Now, If I use the same query to get rest data on that date as following, it return only the records of `2023-01-31`, even after using `` ORDER BY `date` DESC `` in above query.

Below are the queries I'm trying:

```
SELECT * FROM cpr
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(`date`) AS max_date 
    FROM cpr
    WHERE YEAR(`date`) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
    GROUP BY YEAR(`date`), MONTH(`date`)
)
AS monthwise ON cpr.`date` = monthwise.max_date
```

another one:

```
SELECT * FROM cpr
WHERE `date` IN (
    SELECT MAX(`date`)
    FROM cpr
    WHERE YEAR(`date`) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
    GROUP BY YEAR(`date`), MONTH(`date`)
)
```

Any help will be appreciated. TIA :)

Comment: I can't reproduce: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/to6cHiSpsPWGkQaQYEdhqC/0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to replace `*` with `cpr.*` in `SELECT` statement as below:

```
SELECT cpr.*
FROM cpr
INNER JOIN ( 
    SELECT MAX(`date`) AS max_date 
    FROM cpr WHERE YEAR(`date`) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) 
    GROUP BY YEAR(`date`), MONTH(`date`) 
) AS max_dates ON cpr.`date` = max_dates.max_date
```

Comment: Woah! I just made a silly mistake. Thank you so much

Comment: Please format your query and can you explain why this is the answer? Remember that many people might read this in years to come, and they might wonder why you gave this answer. Please add this explanation to the answer itself.

Answer (score 1):

Use window functions! This is simpler, and in general more efficient than a subquery and a self-join:

```
select *
from (
    select c.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by year(date), month(date) order by date desc) rn
    from cpr c
) c
where rn = 1
```

Note: window functions are available in MySQL starting version 8.0.